# Clearing memory references in closures

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question about how closures work in relation to garbage collection. I have created a javascript application that seems to be continually adding objects that don't get cleaned up when I create a new project. In my code the application clears out all the references to the newly created objects and I make sure to unbind all events and dispose them. However when I look in the chrome heap profiler this is what I see:

[image]

When I click on the references of the objects I can see there are pointers to the objects in the jQuery proxy function. (specifically the variable 'context')

From what I can see, the proxy function creates a closure and that closure has a reference to the viewport when its constructed. This is how I'm using the proxies in Viewport3D:

```
//in constructor of Viewport3D
this.keydownProxy = jQuery.proxy( this.onKeyDown, this );
jQuery(document).on( "keydown", this.keydownProxy );
```

...

```
//In dispose method of viewport
jQuery(document).off( "keydown", this.keydownProxy );
this.keydownProxy = null;
```

So as you can see I am removing the events as well as nullifying the proxy where the closure reference exists.

So why does the viewport3d still exist in memory even after the events have been removed and the proxies nullified I know its that section of the code because when I comment out all those created proxies, the class is fully garbage collected.

If its because there is a loose pointer somewhere else keeping this alive, is there any other way I can see where it is coming from in Chrome?

Thanks for any guidance you can provide.

Comment: I can't quite get my head round what's going on but could it be similar to the issue described [here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2298-Be-Careful-When-Using-The-jQuery-Proxy-Method-Outside-Of-A-jQuery-Context.htm)?

Comment: Hi Beetroot-Beetroot, I've actually read that article before. This isn't actually the problem as I'm not binding the jQuery proxy to a separate event system. I'm using the proxy as it's meant to be used (at least as far as I can see) within the jQuery environment. I've stepped through the 'off' function and it definitely is removing the event listener. However it seems to me that even though im nullifying the proxy it still believes its being used in memory. Because of this the Viewport can never be deleted as the proxy 'context' variable still holds a reference to viewport3D :S

Comment: This is why I thought / think that its maybe not deleting the memory because there is still a reference to Viewport3D somewhere other than in the context. But looking at the heap profiler this doesnt seem to be what's reported. As far as the profiler is concerned, the only references to Viewport3D are in the proxy's which Viewport3D owns and has nullified :S

Comment: My thought was that `this.onKeyDown` is a function reference outside of jQuery but I'm not sure, is that Ben N's issue or not?

Comment: Just for test purposes, see if you can call `jQuery.proxy( foo, this )` where `foo` is a function reference not involving `this`, eg a function returned from a dedicated mini-closure, defined in the global namespace. Then inspect to see if the same memory issue still occurs.

Comment: Hi Beetroot. I added this to the class constructor: `for ( var i = 0; i < 1000; i++ ){
  this["testRef" + i.toString()] = jQuery.proxy( function(r){}, this );
  jQuery(document).on( "keydown", this["testRef" + i.toString()] );
 }`. So dynamically added 1000 proxies and events. Then in the dispose method: `for ( var i = 0; i < 1000; i++ ) {
  jQuery(document).off( "keydown", this["testRef" + i.toString()] );
  this["testRef" + i.toString()] = null;
 }`. So basically created an inline function. This creates 1000 left over objects in the heap after the dispose method call :(

Comment: Also tried with a global function, and the result was still the same.

Comment: Mat, you've tested my theory to destruction. It was good while it lasted. There's a couple of other things you can try. (1) In dispose method of viewport, use delete rather than equating to `null`; ie `delete this.keydownProxy;`. (2) In constructor of Viewport3D, use javascript's `.call()` rather than jQuery's `.proxy()`; ie `var that = this; jQuery(document).on( "keydown",  function(evt) { that.onKeyDown.call(that, evt); });`, then in dispose method use the `...off(...)` line on its own (without delete or =null).